# How can I show all the employees who roll up into a given manager using MySQL and recursive CTEs?

Tags: mysql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I need to be able to show how every employee roles up into all levels of their leadership, not just the immediate parent-child relationships. In other words, if there are 500 employees excluding the CEO, the CEO report-in lines would contain 500 rows.

I've seen similar questions where the request is to map the entire hierarchy, but not the cumulative hierarchy.

For example

```
EmployeeId, ManagerId, Name
1, NULL, TheGeneral
2, 1, Bob
3, 1, Christelle
4, 1, Wilfer
5, 2, Hailey
6, 2, George
7, 3, Mary
8, 4, Henry
9, 5, Wendy
```

The output I'm looking for would be

```
ReportIntoManagerId, ManagerialLevel, EmployeeId, Name
NULL, 1, 1, TheGeneral
1, 1, 2, Bob
1, 1, 3, Christelle
1, 1, 4, Wilfer
1, 1, 5, Hailey
1, 1, 6, George
1, 1, 7, Mary
1, 1, 8, Henry
1, 1, 9, Wendy
2, 2, 5, Hailey
2, 2, 6, George
2, 2, 9, Wendy 
3, 2, 3, Christelle
3, 2, 7, Mary
4, 2, 4, Henry
5, 3, 9, Wendy
```

But I can't figure out how to do this. I know it requires using recursive CTEs, but I can't figure out how to get it to do the cumulative roll up. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use Recursive CTE to get the hierarchy for every employee :

```
WITH RECURSIVE employee_paths (EmployeeId, name, path) AS
(
  SELECT EmployeeId, name, CAST(EmployeeId AS CHAR(200))
    FROM employees
    WHERE ManagerId IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT e.EmployeeId, e.name, CONCAT(ep.path, ',', e.EmployeeId)
    FROM employee_paths AS ep JOIN employees AS e
      ON ep.EmployeeId = e.ManagerId
)
SELECT * FROM employee_paths ORDER BY path;
```

Result :

```
EmployeeId  name        path
1           TheGeneral  1
2           Bob         1,2
5           Hailey      1,2,5
9           Wendy       1,2,5,9
6           George      1,2,6
3           Christelle  1,3
7           Mary        1,3,7
4           Wilfer      1,4
8           Henry       1,4,8
```

Then we `JSON_TABLE` to split the comma separated path into rows :

We first Concatenate square brackets ([]) around the string to make it into a JSON array. Then use `JSON_TABLE` to convert it into a table.

```
WITH RECURSIVE employee_paths (EmployeeId, name, path, level) AS
(
  SELECT EmployeeId, name, CAST(EmployeeId AS CHAR(200)), 1
    FROM employees
    WHERE ManagerId IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT e.EmployeeId, e.name, CONCAT(ep.path, ',', e.EmployeeId), level+1
    FROM employee_paths AS ep JOIN employees AS e
      ON ep.EmployeeId = e.ManagerId
)

SELECT j.ReportIntoManagerId, t2.level as ManagerialLevel, t.EmployeeId, t.name
FROM employee_paths t
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(t.path, ',', '","'), '"]'),
                      '$[*]' COLUMNS (ReportIntoManagerId TEXT PATH '$')
                    ) j
INNER JOIN employee_paths t2 ON t2.EmployeeId = j.ReportIntoManagerId
WHERE j.ReportIntoManagerId <> t.EmployeeId OR t.EmployeeId = 1
order by ReportIntoManagerId
```

Result :

```
ReportIntoManagerId ManagerialLevel EmployeeId  name
1   1   1   TheGeneral
1   1   2   Bob
1   1   3   Christelle
1   1   4   Wilfer
1   1   5   Hailey
1   1   6   George
1   1   7   Mary
1   1   8   Henry
1   1   9   Wendy
2   2   5   Hailey
2   2   6   George
2   2   9   Wendy
3   2   7   Mary
4   2   8   Henry
5   3   9   Wendy
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Hiu9GwT2)